# CSS3 for Print media

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

I'm trying generate a page (static html, some parts generated with php) for pdf print output.

Here is the CSS specific to the print version of the page. There are other formatting rules but they are not inside the "@media print" tag:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        @top-right {
            content: "99999999 | L.L.O.";
        }
        orphans: 4;
        widows: 3;

    }

    @page:margin {
        margin: 2cm;
    }

    @page :first {
        margin-top: 10cm;
    }

    @page :left {
        margin-left: 3cm;
        margin-right: 2cm; 
    }

    @page :right {
        margin-left: 2cm;
        margin-right: 3cm;
    }

    div.divHeader {
        position: fixed;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        top: 0;
        text-align: right;
        float: right;
    }

    .do_not_print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

These styles give wildly different results on each breed of browser:

- **Safari on OS X (WebKit)**: Ignores all @page rules, partially renders divHeader but only on first page, and does not render text-align, padding or float commands, renders "page-break-inside" on divs
- **Firefox on OS X (Gecko)**: Similar to Safari, but renders divHeader on all pages
- **Opera on OS X (Presto)**: Renders margin commands!, renders divHeader on random pages (but not its padding components), but only prints the first 4 pages (of 14!)
- **IE on PC (Trident)**: Mostly renders margin (except margin-top), only prints the first two pages but overlays individual divs subsequent to the first page, prints heads and renders positioning parts of it too

I really hope you will find fault with my code...

Thanks kindly for looking!

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit, changing multiple aspects of the code, it was possible to optimize the output for Firefox. Safari, Opera and IE are still screwy. Safari/WebKit has some bugs which make it impossible to render a running head. It may be possible to adjust this css for Opera and IE.

```
@media print {

    @page {
        margin: 2cm;
        orphans: 5;
        widows: 5;
    }

    .title {

        margin: 10cm 0 0 0;
        page-break-after: always;
        display: block;

    }


    div.divHeader {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    img {

        max-width: 98% !important;
        page-break-inside: avoid;

    }

    .do_not_print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```